# Faster way to extract specific pixels from hypercube?

Tags: r, subset

I'm working with image cubes and would like to extract specified individual pixels from all layers (an image cube is similar to a raster stack in that there are N layers, each corresponding to a certain wavelength; each layer is a full 2D image).  I've come up with two approaches:

```
# sample 3-D image cube array
foo<- array(runif(512*512*16),dim=c(512,512,16))
# sample collection of x,y ordered pairs defining the pixels of interest
fooloc<- cbind(sample(1:512,256),sample(1:512,256))

pull1<-function(foo,fooloc) {
bar<-foo[fooloc[,1],fooloc[,2],]
sapply(1:(nrow(fooloc)),function(j)diag(bar[,,j]))
}

pull2 <- function(foo, fooloc) sapply(1:(nrow(fooloc)) ,function(j) foo[fooloc[j,1],fooloc[j,2],])
```

The second one is about 10X faster (per `microbenchmark`).  I just get the feeling that I'm missing something in the capabilities of the `[` operator.  Any ideas?

EDIT: trying Jbaum's `raster` idea:

```
bfoo<-brick(foo)
pull3<-function(foo,fooloc) {
    #foo<-brick(foo)
    locfoo<- nrow(foo)*(fooloc[,1]-1) + fooloc[,2]
    extract(foo,locfoo) #default is all layers
    }
```

the benchmark against the (fixed) `pull2` function is:

```
Unit: microseconds
                expr     min      lq   median       uq      max
 pull3(bfoo, fooloc) 924.523 932.221 1028.435 1041.691 1380.369
  pull2(foo, fooloc) 771.862 793.670  828.307  833.867  979.687
 neval
     5
     5
```

Comment: I think it's actually about ~70% faster, if you pull values from all 16 layers (`pull1` only grabs the first 4 layers at the moment).

Comment: Yep -- sorry for the typo .

Comment: And yes, the `pull2` is wrong too.  I'll fix.

Comment: There's still something not quite right with `pull1` and `pull2`. `subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @jbaums yeah, I probably changed horses midstream and went to `fooloc[,1] fooloc[,2]` in those expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns of `fooloc` represent row (x) and col (y) locations at which you'd like to sample (across all layers) `foo`, then the way you've subset `foo` to create `bar` doesn't make sense to me. The selected rows of `foo` that are retained in `bar` are the row and col number of the first location of interest. The selected columns that are retained in `bar` are the row and column number of the second location of interest. This occurs in both `pull1` and `pull2`.

Assuming you want to drill down through layers' at each point (represented by an x-coordinate given in the first column of `fooloc` and a y-coordinate given in the second column of `fooloc`, then you can use matrix subsetting, whereby you pass a matrix with columns for each dimension (x, y, z in your case), and rows representing locations of interest (i.e., basically your `fooloc` with an additional column for slice number):

```
xyz <- cbind(fooloc[rep(1:256, each=16), ], rep(1:16, 256))

head(xyz, 17)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]  326  264    1
#  [2,]  326  264    2
#  [3,]  326  264    3
#  [4,]  326  264    4
#  [5,]  326  264    5
#  [6,]  326  264    6
#  [7,]  326  264    7
#  [8,]  326  264    8
#  [9,]  326  264    9
# [10,]  326  264   10
# [11,]  326  264   11
# [12,]  326  264   12
# [13,]  326  264   13
# [14,]  326  264   14
# [15,]  326  264   15
# [16,]  326  264   16
# [17,]  244  355    1


baz <- foo[xyz]

# Above, we use fooloc[rep(1:256, each=16), ] to repeat each location 
#  (each row of fooloc) 16 times, and bind a new column to the right. This
#  new column contains the slice number, and repeats the series 1 through 16,
#  256 times.

head(baz, 16)

#  [1] 0.94575793 0.05488447 0.81821761 0.66999710
#  [5] 0.40956337 0.63314819 0.12832025 0.14121603
#  [9] 0.04719879 0.25077312 0.96271159 0.67870516
# [13] 0.66355153 0.23132471 0.11800990 0.04486127
```

These first 16 elements contain the values of the 16 slices at the location given in the first row of `fooloc`. These are identical to the values given by `foo[fooloc[1, 1], fooloc[1, 2], ]`.

The complete `baz` vector has 4096 elements, corresponding to values from the 16 layers extracted at 256 separate locations.

You can bind it to the subsetting matrix to keep track of where they came from:

```
qux <- cbind(xyz, baz)
head(qux)

#                       baz
# [1,] 326 264 1 0.94575793
# [2,] 326 264 2 0.05488447
# [3,] 326 264 3 0.81821761
# [4,] 326 264 4 0.66999710
# [5,] 326 264 5 0.40956337
# [6,] 326 264 6 0.63314819
```

A time comparison with you existing functions is unfair, since `pull1` and `pull2` return 32 elements each, and your question suggests you're after the full 4096. That said, it's still faster than `pull1`.

As a side note, if you can read the file in with `raster()` (from the `raster` package), you can use `extract` to extract the values from all layers, just by providing your `fooloc` as the `y` argument.

Comment: No doubt my `pull1` is sloppy -- I extract a gigantic subset and then extract a small piece of that! I think your `baz` will end up being a memory and timewaster :-( ;  but I'll take  a hack at the `raster::extract` method and let you know.

Comment: @Carl: You might be right, and in fact I didn't include that step in my crude benchmark. Amongst other things, I guess it'll depend on (1) the number of layers of your actual images; (2) the number of query locations; and (3) whether the set of locations changes (and so `baz` would need to be recalculated for each image/analysis).

Comment: Also, be careful with `raster::extract`. Coordinates increase from the lower left corner (less relevant for the example you posted, where you calculate cell number in advance), and cell number increases in row-major order.

Comment: yep I noticed that :-).